# Facebook user authentication in java

Tags: java, facebook

I am able to load my app in facebook iframe, but can anyone help me with the user authentication in java. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All java API clients provide extensive documentation on authentication. Here are two:

- [restfb](http://restfb.com/)
- [spring-social-facebook](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/)

Authentication follows the [OAuth](http://oauth.net/2/) dance, which includes exchanging tokens. A tricky bit is that you should store the initial request token in your session, in order to be able to get it when facebook redirects the user back afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sdk like [this one](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-sdk/) or you can find your way trough the [facebook api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/), the requests are simple.